# How to programmatically know that play services version was updated

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play-services

In my application, I need to implement functionality that will depend on an update to Google Play Services.
Is it possible to dynamically track that the version of Google Play Services has been updated? Maybe there are some events, listeners or broadcast?

Comment: you should be able to get the package info using PackageManager. Then you can read installed version and act accordingly.

Comment: Of course, BUT I need to do it dynamically. Any broadcasts from system???

Comment: you were able to get any package info (thus version) till Android 10. Starting Android 11 you will probably need `<queries>` tag in manifest or maybe new permission `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES`, read this [blog post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/package-visibility-in-android-11-cc857f221cd9), but be aware that you may get refused from publishing in Google Play (due to its policy). there is no corresponing broadcast or any event afaik

Comment: Thanks for answer. Can I use next receiver for detecting version, something like this? <receiver android:name=".Receiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED" />
        <data android:scheme="package" android:path="com.google.android.gms"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver> 
What do you think?